# Hacer que mi web se visualice en distintos dispositivos

Tags: html, html5, web

Estoy creando una pagina web para mi negocio, a la hora de visualizar mi web en PC se ve correctamente, pero cuando abro la página en el móvil el video inicial de mi web es enorme y no se puede ver bien,es decir no redimensiona el tamaño,es una web html5 normal.

¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer para adaptar una misma web para que sea visible tanto en móviles como en PC?

Es mi primera vez y ando bastante perdido.

Comment: Lee [ask], de paso Checa el [tour], para que edites y coloques el código mínimo necesario que permita identificar el problema, pues así como está la pregunta no hay mucho de donde partir

Answer (score 4):

Adaptar la web a los distintos dispositivos es una técnica de diseño llamada: **responsive web design**. Es decir, crear una web que se adapte automáticamente a las distintas resoluciones de pantalla.
Información ampliada en: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).
Hay dos maneras de hacerlo: Utilizando frameworks, que facilitan el trabajo, o usar código propio utilizando las técnicas disponibles.
La etiqueta meta para el viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` fue introducida por Apple en Safari con la misma finalidad hace ya unos cuántos años, y a día de hoy es utilizada en el diseño web con el mísmo propósito.Hay que referenciarla entre la etiqueta `<head>`.
Cambiar píxeles por porcentajes y/o vw facilitará el trabajo.
En las consolas de los navegadores dispones de varias herramientas, concretamente una de ellas se usa para éste diseño adaptable.
Recomendable también comprobar la evolución del trabajo en distintos navegadores, ya que cada navegador usa valores propios por defecto y el comportamiento de tu web puerde variar de un navegador a otro.
Otro punto a tener en cuenta son **@media queries** para diseñar a medida con la ayuda de la consola de tu navegador el comportamiento de la disposición de tu web.
Suerte!!!

Comment: muchisimas gracias !!!

Comment: El enlace provisto no funciona

Comment: Más que una respuesta parecen solo una serie de comentarios, que no sabemos si es lo que ocupa el OP debido a lo amplio de su pregunta

Comment: [ https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp ] Envío el enlace y espero que ahora esté bien... @Aprendiz...quizá a tu parecer son sólo una serie de comentarios, pero estoy segura que le ha servido de guía inicial. Estamos tod@s aprendiéndo, y si no tuviese nada que decir...regalaría mi silencio. Saludos!!

Comment: Quizá se trate de "interpretación", su pregunta es clara, no veo la necesidad de adjuntar un código, tampoco he leído por ninguna parte que sea obligatorio adjuntarlo...y desconocía que ésta web tenga usuarios encargados de emitir votos negativos a personas que se molestan en contestar una pregunta que no necesita ser respaldada por ningún código...Cuestión de carácter amigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte!!! tene en cuenta que no toda pregunta debe contestarse. Se pide que las preguntas y las respuestas sean sobre problemas claros y que tengan una respuesta que no parezca una opinion. Por favor mira [answer] para entender como deben ser las respuestas y [ask] para entender como deben ser las preguntas. La idea de mostrar algo es poder trabajar sobre un problema concreto.

Comment: ¿Alguien sabe que puedo hacer para adaptar una misma web para que sea visible tanto en móviles como en PC?

Adaptar la web a los distintos dispositivos es una técnica de diseño web llamada" responsive web desingn". Es decir, crear una web que se adapte automáticamente a las distintas resoluciones de pantalla.
Y no es una opinión, es un hecho.
Hay dos maneras de hacerlo: utilizando frameworks que facilitan el trabajo,  o usar código propio utilizando las técnicas disponibles.

Comment: La etiqueta meta para el viewport fue introducida por Apple en Safari con la misma finalidad hace ya unos cúantos años…y a día de hoy es utilizada en el diseño web con ése propósito.
Hay que referenciarla entra la etiqueta <head>.
Cambiar píxeles por porcentajes y el texto con vw ayudará con el trabajo.
La consola de firefox en concreto es maravillosa para hacer pruebas y comprobar cómo quedará ya que dispone de una herramienta para el diseño adaptable.

Comment: Importante también ver el resultado en distintos navegadores ya que cada navegador  tiene sus valores por defecto y por lo tanto el comportamiento visual de la web cambia.

Comment: Respecto a si mi respuesta parece  o no una opinón, que no estoy deacuerdo,  y  la doble invitación a leérme cómo responder y  contestar a las preguntas…me ha parecido fuera de lugar, ya sabré yo cuándo y cómo respondo o pregunto. Estoy aquí para aprender, preguntar y responder respetando en todo momento las normas de ésta comunidad y sus navegantes.

Comment: @CodeGood puedes editara tu pregunta, actualizando el enlace que has puesto en los comentarios junto toda la información que has proporcionado que creas relevante. Ten en cuenta que no todo el mundo navega por los comentarios de las respuesta. PD : Aunque tu respuesta puede ser o no correcta ( no lo voy a juzgar yo) esta claro que Krastez ha formulado una pregunta demasiado amplia, ya que en esta pagina se solucionan problemas **concretos** .